# xcodebuild times out when starting simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, teamcity, xcode8, xcodebuild, codesign

I am attempting to set up automated testing for my iOS app using TeamCity. Currently, my agent builds, but once building the last target and running codesign, it hangs and displays the following:

```
[19:29:34][CodeSign] CodeSign /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProductiOS-fgkoogiimhlbckdlbckzmqfyaoff/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProductiOSUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyProductiOSUITests.xctest
[19:29:34][CodeSign]     cd /Users/ericmiller/.tcagent/work/f9abef315a0137d4
[19:29:34][CodeSign]     export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
[19:29:34][CodeSign]     export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/ericmiller/.pyenv/shims:/Users/ericmiller/.rbenv/shims:/Users/ericmiller/.pyenv/shims:/Users/ericmiller/Scripts:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin"
[19:29:34][CodeSign] Signing Identity:     "-"
[19:29:34][CodeSign]     /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProductiOS-fgkoogiimhlbckdlbckzmqfyaoff/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProductiOSUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyProductiOSUITests.xctest
[19:29:34][CodeSign] /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProductiOS-fgkoogiimhlbckdlbckzmqfyaoff/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProductiOSUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyProductiOSUITests.xctest: replacing existing signature
[19:31:32][CodeSign] 2017-01-22 19:31:32.279 xcodebuild[28262:86807]  iOSSimulator: Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1.
[19:31:32][CodeSign] 2017-01-22 19:31:32.290 xcodebuild[28262:86805]  iOSSimulator: Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1.
[19:31:32][CodeSign] 2017-01-22 19:31:32.291 xcodebuild[28262:86797] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProductiOS-fgkoogiimhlbckdlbckzmqfyaoff/Logs/Test/89F7C786-9E91-419F-98CA-F36385618DC2/Session-MyProductiOSTests-2017-01-22_192932-E95vcV.log" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProductiOS-fgkoogiimhlbckdlbckzmqfyaoff/Logs/Test/89F7C786-9E91-419F-98CA-F36385618DC2/Session-MyProductiOSTests-2017-01-22_192932-E95vcV.log}
[19:31:32][CodeSign] 2017-01-22 19:31:32.291 xcodebuild[28262:86797] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProductiOS-fgkoogiimhlbckdlbckzmqfyaoff/Logs/Test/89F7C786-9E91-419F-98CA-F36385618DC2/Session-MyProductiOSUITests-2017-01-22_192932-mrX7wQ.log" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProductiOS-fgkoogiimhlbckdlbckzmqfyaoff/Logs/Test/89F7C786-9E91-419F-98CA-F36385618DC2/Session-MyProductiOSUITests-2017-01-22_192932-mrX7wQ.log}
```

The simulator app is open in the dock. Clicking on the simulator does nothing, but if I right-click and select the window, I can see that the simulator is indeed running but is not displaying anything. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khpwI.png)

I'm looking for a workaround to test my code, without switching to a physical device instead of a simulator if possible. How can I achieve this goal, and what could be wrong with my configuration?

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT:

Sven Driemecker found the solution. Here's my configuration.
Before running the xcodebuild, I run the following shell script to ensure a sanitary testing environment.

```
xcrun simctl shutdown %env.simulator_guid%
killall Simulator
killall com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
xcrun simctl erase %env.simulator_guid%
```

Then, when running the xcodebuild, add the following option:

```
-destination "id=%env.simulator_guid%"
```

And finally, to clean everything up:

```
xcrun simctl shutdown %env.simulator_guid%
killall Simulator
killall com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

**Update:** Here's a [blog post I wrote](https://sosheskaz.github.io/2017/03/07/XCode-CI-Article.html) about how to set up basic TeamCity CI for XCode/iOS.

Comment: Please file a radar and include the output of sysdiagnose -q and the logs from ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems pretty odd, but simply resetting the simulator usually fixes this. We often encounter the same error on our own CI-system.

Try Simulator-Menu -> Reset Content and Settings, then restart the simulator.

You can enforce this on the command line, but I won't recommend it, cause it will slow down your build remarkably.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! This worked perfectly. I'll update my post with exactly what I did to help any future visitors.

Comment: You're welcome! Your automated simulator cleaning on the cmd line looks very similar to what we tried some time ago, but we encountered major performance problems with that. Glad to hear that your approach seems to be pretty fast. Will try it also!

Comment: It wasn't as fast as I initially thought. It added 4 minutes to my build time. However, that's acceptable for this project because I'm the sole dev and the build machine's attention is undivided. Also, since I've automated Carthage, it's building a bunch of stuff anyway. It's also a relatively slow machine, being a minimally specced 2011MBP (albeit with 8G RAM and an SSD).

Comment: By the way, I wrote a start-finish tutorial on setting up TeamCity CI for an iOS XCode project. You seem knowledgeable enough that you don't need it, but if you know someone who does it may be nice to pass along. Also, this way anyone visiting the thread can find it. https://sosheskaz.github.io/2017/03/07/XCode-CI-Article.html

Comment: Great article, never used TeamCity before in favour of Hudson/Jenkins. Will give it a try soon.

Answer (score 5):

I have been experiencing a similar error when attempting to run an iOS app in the simulator from Xcode 11.3.1. I have found that re-choosing the virtual hardware can resolve this issue a little quicker than other solutions mentioned on this page.

When I receive the *"Timed out waiting for Simulator.app to become ready"* error in Xcode, the Simulator.app has typically launched but shows no actual simulator. Choosing `Hardware > Device > [OS version] -> [Simulator Name]` causes the simulator to appear and successfully launch my app on the next run attempt.

Comment: In Xcode 11.4 the simulator menu item has moved to `File > Open Device > [OS version] -> [Simulator Name]`

Comment: Very good description. Can we determine whether this problem is confined to certain systems? I'm seeing this only on Mojave.

Comment: @matt I'm seeing this issue reliably after every restart on macOS 10.15.3 with Xcode 11.3.1 (a common config at the moment I imagine). The only novel thing about my setup is that I have deleted all the stock simulators and subsequently created a single iPhone 11 iOS 13.3 simulator (no paired watch) using the "Devices and Simulators" window.

Comment: I got a similar issue. I eventually solved it by manually removing the app from the simulated device. After that the simulator was able to start debugging normally.

Comment: This issue appears to have been [resolved in Xcode 11.5](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_5_release_notes#3584134) _Fixed some issues where Xcode would sometimes fail to run an app in a simulated device, with an error “Timed out waiting for Simulator.app to become ready”._

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in Xcode 11.3 and earlier which could manifest this way if you have Simulator.app running from another Xcode.  There is a small race window in which this could happen.  That was fixed in Xcode 11.3.1.

but...

There is a bug in Xcode 11.3.1 and later (through Xcode 11.4.1 as of this comment) which manifests this way as well.  To workaround the issue, you can click on Simulator.app in Dock after it launches (even if it is foreground).  Alternatively, you can enable pasteboard synchronization in Simulator.app via 'Edit -> Automatically Sync Pasteboard'.

Comment: Wow, I never would've guessed the automatic pasteboard sync thing, this worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, there was a failure when initializing the pasteboard sync at launch which put the app in an awkward state.  It has been fixed in Xcode 11.5+.

Comment: Thank you, sir! "Automatically Sync Pasteboard" solved the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a good solution to fix the root cause of this issue, but I have found a work around. If you simply open simulator before building your app in Xcode this issue is bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

Just **killing** and **reopening** the simulator worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the `Window` menu of the Simulator app.

There could be one or more Simulator windows that are marked as using an `[External Display]`. When you select a window from the menu nothing will appear, however you will be able to press `Cmd-W` to close it.

After you've closed all windows using an External Display, the Simulator will start working properly again.

I am uncertain how one can select an External Display for a simulator, however it has happened to me a few times and just quitting the Simulator app did not help. I had to either do what I describe above, or restart the machine.